# Offline Update Rhel 7.4 without changing the version of OS

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, yum, rhel-7

I have to Update my Rhel Server and keep the version of OS. 
The current running version of OS is Rhel 7.4.
My server is not connected to internet. So i have to do an offline Update.
Is it possible to do an update using an ISO file of RHEL7.7 or RHEL 7.8, Attach the file to the server , then modify the Yum repo, and execute this command :

```
yum -x 'kernel*' -x 'redhat-release*' update
```

What are the risks? 
what are others Packages that I should Exclude?
Is it the same architecture of files and folders for RHEL 7.4 and 7.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating to a minor version, you will not encounter issues during the update, excluding all kernel related  packages using "kernel*' is enough, also yum will automatically pickup the packages related to your current architecture.